# What's the simplest way to detect if a question was asked by a user whose account has been deleted?

Tags: support, api-v2

What's the minimum filter and simplest way to detect if a question (by its ID) was asked by a user whose account has been deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found [one such question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10338/looking-for-a-sega-genesis-game)

From the `\question\{id}\` route you need the **!YwUIfd5b6** filter:

1. `items` from `.wrapper`
2. `owner` from `question`
3. `user_type` from `shallow_user`

If you get `{"items":[{"owner":{"user_type":"does_not_exist"}}]}` as a response, the owner has been deleted. [Sample query.](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=10338&filter=!YwUIfd5b6&site=gaming&run=true)

(If you instead get `{"items":[]}` then the ID is not a question's or the question has been deleted.)

Comment: A question that was migrated to site where the asker doesn't have an account will show as "does_not_exist" as well (because they don't, on that site); you should check `migrated_from` if you want true "deletions".